# HTML Button not creating alert

Tags: javascript, html, button, addeventlistener

I know I am probably missing something very simple, but why isn't the alert showing up when the button is clicked? Is it something to do with the function within the "addEventListener"?

Thanks!

```js
const button = document.getElementsByTagName("button");

button.addEventListener("click", function(event){
    alert("Heyyyy!")
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title></title>
 </head>
 <body>
     <p>
         <button type="button">Click Me!</button>
     </p>
  <script src=Test.js></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check your console you probably have "addEventListener is not a function" error and that's because

```
document.getElementsByTagName("tag-name")
```

returns an array of DOM elements since a tag name isn't unique across the DOM elements like the id.
so you have two options give the button an id and use

```
document.getElementById("button-id")
```

or just get the first item in the array

```
const button = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];

button.addEventListener("click", function(event){
    alert("Heyyyy!")
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Your suggestions are great. Forgot that the getElementsByTagName returns an array.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use only a function and the onclick property, like this:

**HTML**

```
<button id="myButton" onclick="var msg='message'; alertFunction(msg);">Click Me!</button>
```

**JS**

```
function alertFunction(msg) { alert(msg); }
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because `getElementsByTagName(tagName)` returns an **Array** so you must loop through it to add the event listener.

But if you only needs to add to a specific button, then use id to reference the button.

E.g

To assign to every button:

```
const button = document.getElementsByTagName("button");

Array.from(button).forEach((el) => {
    el.addEventListener("click", function(event){
    alert("Heyyyy!")
    })
});
```

The need for `Array.from(element)` is because **HTML** element is an array-like not a pure array.

To assign to a specific button:

Simply:

`buttonId.addEventListener('click', function(){})`

Comment: Thank you for your help! Forgot that the getElementsbyTagName returns an array

Answer (score 0):

```js
const button = document.getElementsByTagName("button");

button.addEventListener("click", function(event){
    alert("Heyyyy!")
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title></title>
 </head>
 <body>
     <p>
         <button type="button">Click Me!</button>
     </p>
  <script src=Test.js></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Try window.addEventListener();